# Are layout_alignParentRight or layout_alignParentLeft work for include layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-relativelayout

I have a little problem.

I am creating a custom button widget

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/barBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/sel_btn_bar"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
/>
```

Then I place it into the `RelativeLayout`

```xml
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bar"/>
    <include layout="@layout/segm_btn_stores"/>

        <include
                layout="@layout/btn_bar"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But align doesn't work until I place `include` tag into `RelativeLayout` which I can move as I want. But this method is creating another problems: button will be narrower than if it was outside `RelativeLayout`. What can I do? I want to setup button params in one place.

And yes, I can add this line: `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to `Button` tag and it will work!

So the question is: why it works for `Button` tag and doesn't work for `include` tag?

### Update

Button and fragments layout are [there](http://db.tt/4EMEUhPq).

Answer (score 1):

I think the `android:layout_centerVertical` attribute (for your `Button` layout) is only valid in a `RelativeLayout` (at least it's documented in the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` document: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html), hence I wouldn't expect it to work in, say, a `LinearLayout`.

As of the case when the button gets narrower within the `RelativeLayout` than outside it, I don't really know what to say. Given the XML snippet you provided it seems like your `RelativeLayout` is the document root, i.e. moving the `<include ... />` tag outside it would generate illegal XML, hence compile errors (if using Eclipse).

I would actually prefer to define button themes in custom styles, which you then could set up in a application global style xml, like this, for example:

```
<resources>
    <style name="my_custom_style" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/my_button_style</item>
    </style>

    <style name="my_button_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_button_background</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_custom_red_color</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and then you'd set your custom style in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/application_title"
    android:theme="@style/my_custom_style">

    <!-- Your Activities, Services etc goes here -->

</application>
```

Comment: No, it's not a root. It's a `RelativeLayout` where the button should be. If I add a wrapping `RelativeLayout` to `include` (with `wrap_content` params of course) the button will be a bit narrower. Ok, I'll check styles tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem now. Your `RelativeLayout` is part of your complete layout xml. Then I think the button-width-problem lies elsewhere in your layout. If you have the possibility to share the complete XML layout file I could perhaps try to help you find the issue. One possibility could be that the `RelativeLayout` and the button layout (when kept outside of the `RelativeLayout`) compete for the same width.

Comment: Great, thanks! How would you like the (included) button to be placed? should it wrap its content and get horizontally centered within its parent?

Comment: It should wrap its content and should be right-aligned in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about what your problem is. You are trying to take your view out of the relativelayout? If your making a layout, your views are going to have to belong to a ViewGroup. Align doesn't work because your view is outside of the ViewGroup which defines that attribute "RelativeLayout"

Comment: But if I add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` into the `Button` (first code block) it will work. The question is why it works for `Button` tag and doesn't work for `include`.

Comment: What's not working? You said the buttons get narrow, but are aligned to the right if your add this in your include? You need to fix some of your layout properties. I like to specify everything in my RelativeLayout, as opposed to the first two views that you have just added using whatever the defaults are.

Comment: `<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/theplace"> <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentRight="true"> <include> </RelativeLayout> </RelativeLayout>` — button aligned but get narrow; `<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/theplace"> <include android:layout_alignParentRight="true"> </RelativeLayout>` — doesn't work.